# Is it recommended to have a mobx Store for each page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, store, mobx

I am building a single page application with Reactjs and MobX at the frontend (port 3000) and Nodejs and Express at the backend (API, port 4000). I am new to both, MobX and Reactjs and I am trying to set up a well-structured project.
My question is: Is it okay to have a Store for each view?

For example, I have a UserStore which stores the Session information and takes care of the login and logout of the user within the platform. However, after Logging in, I want to redirect the user to the dashboard page. This dashboard page must retrieve information regarding the user, but also it must contact the API and retrieve some data (i.e. Some Todos).
This is how I would do it:

This is the login function in which the redirection to Dashboard is made:

`*UserStore.js*`

```
[...]
import  navigationStore  from './NavigationStore';

[...]

login = async (user) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/session/login', { 
      username: user.username, 
      password: user.password 
    });

    this.saveUser(res.data);
    navigationStore.push('/dashboard'); 
  } catch (error) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

And, then, I have created a DashboardStore.js which has the following code:

`*DashboardStore.js*`

```
[... imports and initializations ...]
class Store {

  @observable todos = null

  constructor() {
    this.getDashboard();
  }

  @action('Load dashboard') getDashboard =  async () => { 
    const res = await axios.get('/api/dashboard/', {});    
    this.todos = res.todos
  }

}

const DashboardStore = new Store();

export default DashboardStore;
```

But this would mean that I'd end up doing another Store for the Todos page and another Store for whatever page I'd need.
In NodeJs you can make a controller for each class and there's nothing weird about it. However, I'm not sure that's how it works on MobX.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of your app. I wouldn't create a store for each view or concern, but you could create two, like the MobX docs recommend: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html.

I'm working on a bigger project right now, and we started with a single store for everything. Obviously, it grew a lot as we kept adding functionality, so I think we might split it at some point to reduce complexity.